# Create separate temporary table/view and variables for every query

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-5.6, temporary-tables

How can I create something similar to `VIEW` or `TEMPORARY TABLE` for every query separately?

I have 1 process, it creates and holds one connection (doesn't destroy connection after request, so doesn't destroy temporary tables) the whole time it's running. I have multiple users connecting to this one process randomly and I performing queries for which I need to store some **variables** and also **resultsets** of parts of the query for re-using them.

They cannot be stored as `@variables` and temporary tables in order not to interfere to other queries.

Comment: why  not add column "user" and sort data using it? after change you just add "user" tag to all queries you perform to database: like .. select var, val  from tmp where user = xxx 
or instead of using user you can use session id or if user can run same process twice at same time , use process id to group data

Comment: If the variables and temp data are created per user, it would probably be easier to offload it as session data in the end-user application rather than making the database handle it all - especially if it won't be reused in subsequent user connections.